# SimpleInjector unexpected behaviour of explicitly registered singleton collection

Tags: c#, simple-injector

In [SimpleInjector documentation](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collections) it is said:

> Simple Injector preserves the lifestyle of instances that are returned
>   from an injected `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>`,
>   `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` instance. In reality you
>   should not see the the injected `IEnumerable<T>` as a collection of
>   instances; you should consider it a stream of instances. Simple
>   Injector will always **inject a reference to the same stream** (the
>   `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>` itself is a singleton) and **each time
>   you iterate the `IEnumerable<T>`**, for each individual component, the
>   **container is asked to resolve the instance based on the lifestyle** of
>   that component.

After reading this I expected that after I've registered all `IFoo` and `IFoo<T>` as singletons, `IEnumerable<IFoo>` will be singleton itself and it enumeration will always lead to the same objects.

But this piece of code doesn't work like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using SimpleInjector;

class Program
{
    interface IFoo{}
    interface IFoo<T> : IFoo{}
    class Foo : IFoo<Foo>{}

    class Consumer1
    {
        public IFoo<Foo> FooInstance { get; }
        public Consumer1(IFoo<Foo> fooInstance){FooInstance = fooInstance;}
    }

    class Consumer2
    {
        public IFoo<Foo> FooInstance { get; }
        public Consumer2(IFoo<Foo> fooInstance){FooInstance = fooInstance;}
    }

    class Consumer3
    {
        public IEnumerable<IFoo> FooIntances { get; }
        public Consumer3(IEnumerable<IFoo> fooIntances){FooIntances = fooIntances;}
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cont = new Container();

        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Where(x =>
                                    typeof(IFoo<>).IsAssignableFrom(x) ||
                                    typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                            .Where(x => !x.IsInterface);

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var genericFoo = type.GetInterfaces().Single(x=>x.IsGenericType);
            var genericArgs = genericFoo.GenericTypeArguments;
            var closedGenericFoo = typeof(IFoo<>).MakeGenericType(genericArgs);

            var reg = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(type, cont);

            cont.AddRegistration(closedGenericFoo, reg);
            cont.AddRegistration(typeof(IFoo), reg);
        }

        cont.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(new[] {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()});

        var cons1 = cont.GetInstance<Consumer1>();
        var cons2 = cont.GetInstance<Consumer2>();
        var cons3_1 = cont.GetInstance<Consumer3>();
        var cons3_2 = cont.GetInstance<Consumer3>();

        // Expected: true | Actually: true
        Console.WriteLine($"cons1.FooInstance == cons2.FooInstance : {cons1.FooInstance == cons2.FooInstance}"); 
        // Expected: true | Actually: true
        Console.WriteLine($"cons3_1.FooInstances == cons3_2.FooInstances : {cons3_1.FooIntances == cons3_2.FooIntances}");
        // Expected: true | Actually: false
        Console.WriteLine($"cons3_1.FooIntances.First() == cons1.FooInstance : {cons3_1.FooIntances.First() == cons1.FooInstance}");
        // Expected: true | Actually: false
        Console.WriteLine($"cons3_1.FooIntances.First() == cons3_2.FooIntances.First() : {cons3_1.FooIntances.First() == cons3_2.FooIntances.First()}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. single `Foo` implementation registered to both `IFoo<Foo>` and to
   `IFoo` (partially works)
2. single stream of `IFoo` which is `IEnumerable<IFoo>` (it works)
3. Iterating of `IEnumerable` above should give me same `Foo`
   implementation (doesn't work)

Is it possible?

Comment: Please call `Container.Verify()` at the end of the registration phase. This will result in an exception that explains why your expectations are not met.

Comment: @Steven it doesn't :) It said that I have 3 registrations for `Foo`: 1) Singleton `IFoo`, 2) Singleton `IFoo<Foo>`, and 3) Transient `IFoo`. 3rd one come out of nowhere. It explains why `IEnumerable<IFoo>` creates new `IFoo` everytime, but it doesn't explain how can I avoid transient registration of `IFoo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is the following:

The call to `cont.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(new[] {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()})` results in the following registration:

```
cont.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(new[] { typeof(Foo) });
```

When the collection is resolved for the first time, the container will look up the registration for `Foo` to make sure it will reuse that registration and thus its lifestyle.

With your registration however, no registration for `Foo` can be founds. There are registrations however for `IFoo<Foo>` and `IFoo` but what Simple Injector is concerned, those are different registrations.

As a result of this, Simple Injector will create a last-minute registration for `Foo` on your behalf and the default lifestyle that is used by Simple Injector is `Transient`.

This is why although you already registered `Foo` twice (once as `IFoo<Foo>` and once as `IFoo`), the element of the collection will still be transient.

You would have noticed this problem if you had called `Container.Verify()` at the end of the registration process. Simple Injector detects these kinds of misconfigurations for you. You should always call `Container.Verify()`.

To solve this, you can change your configuration to the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new Container();

    // GetTypesToRegister can do the assembly scanning for you.
    IEnumerable<Type> types = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IFoo<>), 
        new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });

    // Here we create a list of Registration instance once.
    Registration[] regs = (
        from type in types
        select Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(type, container))
        .ToArray();

    // Here we register the registrations as one-to-one mapping.
    foreach (var reg in regs)
    {
        Type closedGenericFoo = reg.ImplementationType.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IFoo<>))
            .Single();

        container.AddRegistration(closedGenericFoo, reg);
    }

    // Here we make a one-to-many mapping between IFoo and the registrations.
    container.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(regs);

    container.Verify();

    ...
}
```

Comment: That is great answer. However I cannot use `Verify()` in my real project because of `Akka.Net`. After I register all actors in container `Verify()` throws error because it tries to create actor instances and `Akka.Net` simple doesn't allow to create actors outside of framework. But that's another story.

Comment: @Szer: If Akka.Net is in control over the creation of actors, and not Simple Injector, you should *not* register those actors in Simple Injector. You should [keep your configuration verifiable](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration) at all times.

Comment: actually SimpleInjector creates actors but deeply inside of some `Resolver` which injected in framework itself. So I have to register them explicitly. SimpleInjector just cannot create these actor instances outside of framework.

Comment: Probably this Akka.Net problem with SimpleInjector worth another question